# ko.toJSON is always making my Date -3 hours

Tags: javascript, date, knockout.js

I have a `momentjs` date object in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` but when i use `ko.toJSON` the hour is **always** -3 hours.

For example, if i have `date` like `2017-06-03 13:00` before `ko.toJSON` after that i get `2017-06-03 10:00` no matter what the hour is, its always -3 hours. What can be the problem?

I get the date from a `datepicker` like this:

```
.on('changeDate', function (e) {
       self.objCurrentResource().SelectedDate(moment(e.date).format("DD-MM-YYYY"));
       self.ConfirmData().Date(moment(e.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
   });
```

and then when the time is selected i concatenate it like this:

```
self.ConfirmData().Date(moment(self.ConfirmData().Date() + " " + data.name));
```

`data.name` is a **string** containing the selected `HH:mm` and i get the results i want.

Comment: What timezone are you working in?

Comment: It's a timezone thing, ko.toJSON probably converts the moment to a UTC datestring while you are picking a local timestring?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.ConfirmData().Date(moment.utc(self.ConfirmData().Date() + " " + data.name).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

This is how i managed to solve it. If anyone needs it in future.

Comment: Solve what? The question is not clearly expressed, nor is the answer. Since you haven't told the parser the format of the string you're parsing, you're leaving it up to the parser to guess. By convention, a string like "2017-06-03 13:00" should be parsed as local (according to the host timezone offset) or invalid. By using *moment.utc* you're forcing it to be treated as UTC. You also don't specify the value of *data.name*, which is appended to the string and may affect the outcome, or not. So it's not clear what you are parsing or why, or what you want the result to be.